# Gas heater fan noise

Tags: hvac, gas, heater

I have a CF653C-H Cozy wall gas heater ..The fan runs fine , except when it shuts down , it clicks 15 to 20  times before stopping . At least I am guessing its the fan, could also be the motor ..But there is no issues during the normal run.

Comment: I am wondering if the bearings are worn as the fan stops moving enough air the blades or cage comes in contact with the housing, fans start quickly so it may not be noticeable on start up.

Comment: It is possible the motor moved on its mount or the mound was bent enough to move the blade off of center. That should be relatively easy to fix. While you are at it if it  has oil cups add some oil.

Answer (score 1):

If the wall heater is very old, the motor could be a split phase or capacitor start motor with a start winding switch. Sometimes when these motors get worn the start winding switch will make noise that is noticeable when the motor  is coasting to a stop. It could also be worn motor bearings which can be checked by moving the shaft up and down to see if there is any up/down play. By checking the replacement parts list I see that the replacement motor has a different model number than the original which usually indicates an older unit. If it is the switch that is making the noise that does not mean that the motor is worn out, it's just worn.

Answer (score 0):

As with Ed, it also sounds to me like you may have bearings that are going dry in the blower motor.  When these bearings dry out they can also make a ticking noise without any outside help. Once you rule everything else out, I would replace the motor.